# What the difference between 発達、発展、発育

Tags: meaning, usage

発達:はったつ
、発展:はってん、、発育:はついく
n3語彙

Answer (score 1):

They all mean "development", but you have to choose the right word depending on what is the developing object.

- **発育**: a human (from a baby to an adult), a pet
- **発展**: a city (from a village to a large country), an organization (from a small workshop to a conglomerate), an event
- **発達**: a skill, an organ (brains, muscles, extremities, etc)